# How to linearize this IF-THEN Constraint?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a nonlinear constraint as below

If $x_k=0$, Then $||{\bf w}_k||==0$

If $x_k=1$, Then $||{\bf w}_k||>0$

Here,

$x_k\in\{0,1\}$ is a binary variable and $||\bf x||$ is the norm of vector $\bf x$.

${\bf w}_k\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$ is also an optimization variable. It is a vector of complex elements.

How can I linearize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic big-M model would be

$$
-Mx_k \leq w_k \leq Mx_k, ~||w_k||\geq \epsilon -M(1-x_k)
$$

However, this is a nasty model as you have a non-convex constraint on the norm. Hence, you will have to work on an elementwise level to force at least one element to be non-zero. To do that, introduce a binary vector $y_k$ to indicate that corresponding element in $w_k$ is positive, and a binary vector $z_k$ to indicate negative, and you could use

$$
-Mx_k \leq w_k \leq Mx_k,~w_k \geq \epsilon - M(1-y_k), ~w_k \leq -\epsilon + M(1-z_k), ~\sum_i y^i_k + \sum_i z^i_k = x_k
$$

...and now I saw you have a complex-valued vector. Simply repeat the same elementwise model for both the real and imaginary part, i.e. effectively define a new vector $w_k$ by stacking the real and imaginary part in a vector twice as large.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any comment on the values of epsilon and M? Would you also elaborate on how it satisfies these two conditions/cases?

Comment: Strict inequalities makes no sense in practical optimization, so you will have to come up with a significantly large $\epsilon$ which is non-zero to you, and doesn't drown in the general precision and tolerance of numerical solvers (typically around, say, $10^{-7}$ or so). $M$ is selected so that the constraints don't influence the optimal solution/feasible set when the condition doesn't hold, i.e. in these models it would be an upper bound on the magnitude of the elements of $w_k$. To see the logic, simply think through what the constraints say if you fix $x$ to the two possible values.

Comment: Thanks @Johan Löfberg You saved me from having to answer this at the CVX Forum.

Answer (score 0):

What about $\langle\exists r :: r \gt 0 \land ||{\bf w}_k|| = x_k \cdot r\rangle$?

For $x_k = 0$:
$\langle\exists r :: r \gt 0 \land ||{\bf w}_k|| = 0 \cdot r\rangle$
$\equiv \langle\exists r :: r \gt 0 \land ||{\bf w}_k|| = 0 \rangle$
$\equiv \langle\exists r :: r \gt 0 \rangle \land ||{\bf w}_k|| = 0$
$\implies ||{\bf w}_k|| = 0$

For $x_k = 1$:
$\langle\exists r :: r \gt 0 \land ||{\bf w}_k|| = 1 \cdot r\rangle$
$\equiv \langle\exists r :: r \gt 0 \land ||{\bf w}_k|| = r \rangle$
$\implies \langle\exists r :: ||{\bf w}_k|| \gt 0 \rangle$
$\equiv ||{\bf w}_k|| \gt 0$

Comment: not clear! Would you please explain it?

Comment: OK, the notation $\langle\exists x : R(x) : T(x)\rangle$, which equivales to $\langle\exists x :: R(x) \land T(x)\rangle$, denotes _existential quantification_. It is a boolean expression that means: _there exists $x$ (in this case, in the domain of real numbers) such that it satisfies $R(x)$ and $T(x)$_. $R(x)$ and $T(x)$ are predicates (i. e. boolean-valued functions), and are called the _range_ and the _term_, respectively. $\land$ (the logical-**and** symbol) has the properties that it distributes over existential quantification and $x \land y \implies y$.

Comment: If the above is still not clear, or you still have any more questions/requests just tell me.

Comment: I must admit that I might not really know about linear optimization, so maybe my answer isn't really applicable to your problem. I just observed that the quantified expression above amounts to the two constraints you have presented, so I thought it could be useful somehow, but I confess I'm not sure.